# Rails if statement results in illegal octal digit error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following if statement in my view:

```
<% if @kase.jobno[1,2].to_i == 10 then %>
  <img src="../images/2010.jpg" alt="2010">
<% elsif @kase.jobno[1,2].to_i == 11 then %>
  <img src="../images/2011.jpg" alt="2011">
<% else %>
  <img src="../images/document.jpg" alt="Document" />
<% end %>
```

It works absolutely perfectly, however, if I want to extend the range of the statement to show a particular image if the @kase.jobno field includes the number 08 and the change the statement to the following:

```
<% if @kase.jobno[1,2].to_i == 09 then %>
  <img src="../images/20109.jpg" alt="2009">
<% elsif @kase.jobno[1,2].to_i == 10 then %>
  <img src="../images/2010.jpg" alt="2010">
<% elsif @kase.jobno[1,2].to_i == 11 then %>
  <img src="../images/2011.jpg" alt="2011">
<% else %>
  <img src="../images/document.jpg" alt="Document" />
<% end %>
```

then I get the following error:

```
Illegal octal digit
```

which points to the 09 value.

Is it impossible to have an if statement which compares against an 0X (number starting with zero and followed by other digit) number?

Thanks,

Danny

Comment: Why do you need to compare against a `0x` number in the first place? Shouldn't this be a string comparison?

Comment: With 0X he meant an octal number, at first I misinterpreted it as hex as well

Comment: Hi Pekka, to be honest I don't understand enough to answer the question. We have job numbers which are M09-123, where M is always present, 09 is the current year and the 123 is the unique (for that year) identifier. So I wanted to compare the year part.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Sorry - I meant 0 followed by X number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting a number with 0 tells Ruby that it is an octal number. 09 is an illegal octal number since those numbers count from 0 to 7 (and not to 9). So after 07 comes 010 which is 8 in the decimal system, followed by 011 which is decimal 9.

If you want to check if the year is 2009 you could use this check:

```
<% if @kase.jobno[1,2].to_i == 9 then %>
  <img src="../images/2009.jpg" alt="2009">
<% end %>
```

(so just remove the 0 in front of 09)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, just do the comparison with the string

```
<% if @kase.jobno[1,2] == "09" then %>
  <img src="../images/20109.jpg" alt="2009">
```